# laravel 5 custom 404

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5

This is driving me crazy. I'm working with Laravel 5 and it appears that the docs for 4.2 and generating 404 pages does not work.

First, there is no global.php so I tried putting the following in routes.php:

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return Response::view('errors.missing', array(), 404);
});
```

This results in an error "method missing() not found"

Debug is set to false.

I've searched and searched but so far have found no information on setting 404 pages in Laravel 5. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Thanks to another user, I found the solution. Adding $handler->missing() to ErrorServiceProvider does the trick. Hope this helps others in the fuutre.

Comment: Please post that as an answer to your question.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26630985/how-do-i-catch-exceptions-missing-pages-in-laravel-5

Comment: This might help you https://codezen.io/how-to-create-a-custom-404-page-in-laravel-7/

Answer (score 63):

Go to resources/views/errors and create a 404.blade.php file with what you want on your 404 page and Laravel takes care of the rest.

Comment: this will work, but this is not something fully controlled by developer, as you can't use your error view inside your layout. You can see my answer.

Comment: @HaykAghabekyan, your answers is not appropiate, because you are editing core files. This answer is the correct because you can use the error view inside of layout using `@extends()` tag.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You can even use Twig if you want more control using `404.twig` and L5 does the rest. Since it's twig, feel free to extend any template you want.

Comment: Yes, you can use `@extends()`, but how do you set variables which are used in parent view? e.g. you have header and footer with menus.

Comment: $exception->getMessage() doesn't return the "File not found" error you see on the Laravel 404 page however, so you can't get the exception message from Laravel, that's a bit annoying as it works for others

Comment: Best solution, also works with Laravel-8,

Answer (score 15):

if you want to have some global solution, you can do changes in /app/Exceptions/Handler.php by adding code bellow

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($this->isHttpException($e)) {

        $statusCode = $e->getStatusCode();

        switch ($statusCode) {

            case '404':
                return response()->view('layouts/index', [
                    'content' => view('errors/404')
                ]);
        }
    }
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer. If you're using Twig or some other templating engine other than Blade then this allows you to load it like a normal view. Although, I must ask what is `layouts/index`? I named both to `errors.404` and it worked.

Comment: layouts is my folder for keeping main template files in it, such as index, which is my default template file.

Answer (score 5):

In Laravel 5 you could simply put a custom **404.blade.php** under **resources/views/errors** and that's it. For other errors like 500 you could try the following in your **app/Exeptions/Handler.php**:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{

    if ( ! config('app.debug') && ! $this->isHttpException($e)) {
        return response()->view('errors.500');
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

And do the same for 500 HTTP Exeptions

Answer (score 3):

I like the case statement approach but it has some issues going levels deep.

However, this catches all errors:

```
Route::any('/{page?}',function(){
  return View::make('errors.404');
})->where('page','.*');
```

Answer (score 2):

Laravel 5 already has a pre-defined render method(line 43) under app/Exceptions/Handler.php. Simply insert the redirection code before parent::render. Like so,

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) 
    {
        $e = new NotFoundHttpException($e->getMessage(), $e);
    }

    //insert this snippet
    if ($this->isHttpException($e)) 
    {
        $statusCode = $e->getStatusCode();
        switch ($statusCode) 
        {
            case '404': return response()->view('error', array(), 404);
        }
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Note: My view is under resources/views. You can somehow put it anywhere else you want.

Comment: Note that `parent::render($request, $e)` transforms some exceptions (`ModelNotFoundException`) into `HttpException`s. These will not be handled by the override added here.

Answer (score 2):

**Lavavel 5.8**

Create a file in `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php` and add this code.

```
@extends('errors::minimal')

@section('title', __('Not Found'))
@section('code', '404')

@if($exception)
    @section('message', $exception->getMessage())
@else
    @section('message', __('Not Found'))
@endif
```

Then in your controller you can use:

```
abort(404, 'Whatever you were looking for, look somewhere else');
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an answer to something else but thought I'd help in case someone else is looking for this.

run the command **php artisan vendor:publish**
you will see all publishable files.  type in the number for laravel-errors
the error files are then published to resources/views/errors folder

Answer (score 0):

You need to create **errors** folder  inside **resources/views** and place your **404.blade.php** file inside errors folder.

It will do the work. you do not need to edit **handler.php** file inside **App/Exception** folder.

Answer (score 0):

**set for Particulier prefix and with custom condition**

```
Route::fallback(function(Request $request) {
    if($request->is('practitioner/*')) {
        return response()->view('errors.practitioner-404', [], 404);
    } else if( $request->is('patient/*') ) {
        return response()->view('errors.patient-404', [], 404);
    } else {
        abort(404);
    }
});
```