# How to show the 404 page?

Tags: php, exception, laravel-5

I would like to show 404 page in Laravel 5 while `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` throws.

Can anyone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 12):

Add this to `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e) 
{
    if ($e instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) 
    {
        abort(404);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Then edit `resource/views/errors/404.blade.php` to personalize the page.

Comment: Remember to add `use \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException` at the start of the file if you don't want to use the full namespace

Answer (score 3):

Simple: all you have to do is create a template at **resources/views/errors/404.blade.php**.

You can create views for other HTTP status codes if you’re feeling that way inclined, such as a **403.blade.php** for Forbidden exceptions and so on.

Comment: OP is asking how to display a 404 page when a specific error is thrown, not how to edit the template for the 404 error itself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on Laravel 5.2 and the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26630985/how-do-i-catch-exceptions-missing-pages-in-laravel-5) worked for me.

You need to modify the render method in the app/Exceptions/Handler.php.

```
    public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        if ($e instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException) 
        {
            return response(view('errors.404'), 404);
        }

        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
```

**`abort(404)` did not work for me.** Looks like this method is removed in Laravel 5.

Answer (score 0):

That's a 405 error, easiest way would be to create a new view in `resources/views/errors/405.blade.php.`.

If you need fine control over what is displayed then you'll have to use the Handler.php to modify what's returned.