# Twilio PHP Error Handing Not Working for SMS

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I am using the Rest API in my php cron for Twilio.
What I am trying to do is loop through all records from my database that require a text message, and then send them a text.

The code works fine, but if there's an error thrown the script breaks down.  I thought I'm using the Exception properly in a try/catch, but it doesn't seem to grab any errors and continue the sms loop.

```
<?php
chdir(dirname(__FILE__)); //need this line so cron works! cron doesn't know the relative file paths otherwise.
require_once 'core/init.php';
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Use the REST API Client to make requests to the Twilio REST API
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
$sid = 'mySid';
$token = 'myToken';
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

$db = DB::getInstance();

$appts = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT appointments.id, contacts.id AS contact_id, CONCAT(contacts.first_name, ' ', contacts.last_name) AS contact_name, contacts.cell_phone, appointments.start AS appt_time, locations.name AS location_name, locations.phone AS location_phone, locations.sms_from_number, companies.name AS company_name
FROM 
appointments 
LEFT JOIN contacts ON contacts.id = appointments.contact_id
LEFT JOIN locations ON locations.id = appointments.location_id
LEFT JOIN companies ON companies.id = appointments.company_id
WHERE appt_status_id IN (2,9,10) AND 
(DATE(`start`) = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND locations.sms_appt_reminders = 'Y' AND contacts.cell_phone IS NOT NULL AND contacts.cell_phone <> '' AND appointments.allDay = 0");

if ($appts->error()) {
    echo 'Error occurred.'; 
} else {

    if ($appts->results()) {

        foreach($appts->results() AS $result) {

            $date = date_create($result->appt_time);
            //remove spaces, remove parentheses, hyphen, add +1 US country code.
            $formatted_cell_number = str_replace(' ', '', $result->cell_phone);
            $formatted_cell_number = str_replace('(', '', $formatted_cell_number);
            $formatted_cell_number = str_replace(')', '', $formatted_cell_number);
            $formatted_cell_number = str_replace('-', '', $formatted_cell_number);
            $formatted_cell_number = '+1' . $formatted_cell_number;

            try {

                // Use the client to send text messages!
                $client->messages->create(
                    $formatted_cell_number,
                    array(
                        'from' => $result->sms_from_number,
                        'body' => 'You have an appointment at ' . $result->company_name . ' (' . $result->location_name . ' office) tomorrow at ' . date_format($date, 'g:i A') . '. Please respond \'C\' to confirm this appointment. Please reply \'R\' if you need to reschedule, or call us at ' . $result->location_phone
                    )
                );

                DB::getInstance()->query("INSERT INTO sms_notifications (contact_id, sms_to_number, sms_from_number, sms_message, category_id, appt_id) VALUES ('".$result->contact_id."', '".$formatted_cell_number."', '".$result->sms_from_number."', 'Contact TEXTED to confirm appoinment on:  ".$result->appt_time."', '0', '".$result->id."')");

            } catch(Exception $e) {

                echo $e->getStatus()."<br>";

            }

        }

    }
}

?>
```

I'm sure there are other ways to clean up this code, but I need to catch and handle the errors first.  As you can see, once a text is sent, I am logging that in a database table for my program's use.   All this works fine as long as there are no errors.  Right now, if I 'unsubscribe' myself from the SMS, this cron.php page shows a HTTP 500 server error, breaking the SMS loop!

UPDATES BELOW

On my local server I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Twilio\Exceptions\EnvironmentException::getStatus() in C:\Users\miche\Google Drive\Server\htdocs\test\cron_sms_appt_reminders.php:59 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Users\me\Google Drive\Server\htdocs\test\cron_sms_appt_reminders.php on line 59
```

line 59 is echo 'error: ' . $e->getStatus()."
";

I notice there is an included php page in the Exceptions folder in the API that is this:

```
namespace Twilio\Exceptions;


class RestException extends TwilioException {
    protected $statusCode;

    /**
     * Construct the exception. Note: The message is NOT binary safe.
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/exception.construct.php
     * @param string $message [optional] The Exception message to throw.
     * @param int $code [optional] The Exception code.
     * @param int $statusCode [optional] The HTTP Status code.
     * @since 5.1.0
     */
    public function __construct($message, $code, $statusCode) {
        $this->statusCode = $statusCode;
        parent::__construct($message, $code);
    }

    /**
     * Get the HTTP Status Code of the RestException
     * @return int HTTP Status Code
     */
    public function getStatusCode() {
        return $this->statusCode;
    }


}
```

Comment: Please see the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32034259/twilio-catching-error-does-not-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that changing $e->getStatus() to $e->getStatusCode() works on my live server.  In case anyone comes across this, that did the trick to catch the error properly.