# Laravel 5.0 - NotFoundHttpException in compiled.php

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have Laravel 5.0 version, whenever the user types any route that wasnt present, system throws the following exception message.

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

1/1
NotFoundHttpException in compiled.php line 7959:
in compiled.php line 7959
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 7230
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 7202
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 7194
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 2040
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 9244
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Debugbar.php line 49
at Debugbar->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 9236
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 2548
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 29
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 9236
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 12416
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 9236
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 11106
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 9236
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 12118
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 9236
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 12066
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 9236
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 2589
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 9236
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 9227
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 1996
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 1983
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

I have checked the permissions for storage folder as well, which is already set as 0755. Also I have already tries php artisan clear-compiled php artisan optimize php artisan cache:clear, but still it didnt work.

This error is happening only when the user types a route that wasnt present, for rest of the routes that already exists in route.php the site is working fine.

Any help in fixing the issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: please use this      

php artisan clear-compiled 
php artisan optimize 
php artisan cache:clear

Comment: Already tried php artisan clear-compiled php artisan optimize php artisan cache:clear, but it didnt work.

Comment: put debug mode off, it should render 404 page

Comment: please check this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26630985/how-do-i-catch-exceptions-missing-pages-in-laravel-5

Comment: Already debug mode is set as OFF and ENV is set as PROD
APP_ENV=prod
APP_DEBUG=false

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26630985/how-do-i-catch-exceptions-missing-pages-in-laravel-5

Comment: @PardeepPathania: That URL explains how to add error page for 404 error, for 404 page not found we'll get RouteNotFoundException, whereas in my case I'm getting NotFoundHttpException in compiled.php. I think they are different scenarios.