# How to make 404 page in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When I try to open page that does exists I get the default error message.
How can I make 404 page in these cases?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel 5 custom 404](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26394017/laravel-5-custom-404)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new file `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php`

Style your page whatever you want, Laravel will match HTTP error code with view filename accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

**Lavavel 5.8**

If you would like to use Laravel's 404 template, create a file in `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php` and add this code.

```
@extends('errors::minimal')

@section('title', __('Not Found'))
@section('code', '404')

@if($exception->getMessage())
   @section('message', $exception->getMessage())
@else
   @section('message', __('Not Found'))
@endif
```

Then in your controller you can use:

```
abort(404, 'Whatever you were looking for, look somewhere else');
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a new file resources/views/errors/404.blade.php

then use abort(404) in route or controllers.

Comment: I need that it work automatically if I call not existing page or routing