# Trying to return custom 404 page Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have some problems with implementing custom 404 error.

My errorHandlerController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ErrorHandlerController extends Controller
{
    public function errorCode404()
    {
        return view('errors.404');
    }

    public function errorCode405()
    {
        return view('errors.405');
    }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('404',['as'=>'404','uses'=>'ErrorHandlerController@errorCode404']);
```

In some other controller I am trying to do this:

```
return redirect()->route('404');
```

It does not show any errors but at network console I see this(endless 302)
[image]

But if I use

```
return view('errors.404');
```

everything works as it should.

Somebody help me please, is something wrong with my routes or else?

Comment: redirect()->route('404'); is the most unessecary thing ever. why do you do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel 5 custom 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26394017/laravel-5-custom-404)

Comment: Checkout this tutorial https://codezen.io/how-to-create-a-custom-404-page-in-laravel-7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize error views really easy in laravel. For example for 404, 403, 500, just put your own template/markup in:

```
resources/views/errors/404.blade.php
resources/views/errors/403.blade.php
resources/views/errors/500.blade.php
```

and you trigger them with the [abort](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-abort) or [abort_if](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-abort-if) helpers
as explained in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/errors#http-exceptions)

Answer (score 2):

Simply just use abort(404); instead of redirect to a custom 404 URL.